# Unable to Copy or Could not Copy "c:\pagefile.sys" and "c:\hiberfile.sys". Exceeded retry count of 10. Faild

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I faced with this error. Can someone help me on this.
The project will build successfully but can't run.

[image]

Comment: I think it's because you can't access the pagefile and hiberfile as those are system files that contain parts of the memory so memory protection applies which means only the system can access them.

Comment: @Nefrin The problem solved by downgrading the DotNetCompilerPlat library. And in my Application I didnt check that file and had no need to them

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer the problem was because of the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlat` library `1.0.1` 
Just downgrade to 1.0.0

Comment: This will fix the build, but doesn't explain how to successfully use the latest version of the package.

Comment: My installed version already 1.0.0. I am not upgrade that plugin.

Comment: @toha in my case the cause of error was because of upgrading. check your other plugin upgrade.